# Which is good app to take pics using web camera in ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, camera

I want to take photograph of me using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: cheese software

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a built in app called cheese webcam booth in Ubuntu 14.04.
You can open it from launcher.
It can be used to take photographs as well as videos.

Comment: And every time I use it I have to search on the web because it doesn't come up if you type 'camera' in ubuntu's app search

Comment: it's so buggy and crashes and slow and choppy

Comment: @PeteKirkham, edit `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Cheese.desktop` file and add `camera` to `Keywords` field. for ex. `Keywords=camera;photo;video;webcam;`. This fixed the issue for me. It should have been a default keyword for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Cheese is perfectly good app which will serve your purpose

if not pre-installed download it from here:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/cheese/

kamoso is also a good one

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/kamoso/